# Validate an expected object structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, validation

I need to have an expected format for the response object in my script as:

```
  let expectedObjectFormat = {
    data: 'someValue',
    errors: 'someValue',
    abort: 'someValue',
    retryData: 'someValue'
  }
```

I need to have a validation script that would check if the runTimeObject has fields in the expected format or not.

1. If there's any field missing it should be reported.
2. If there are any extra fields that should be reported.

```
let runtimeObjectFormat = {
    data: 'someDifferentValue',
    errors: 'someDifferentValue',
    abort: 'someDifferentValue',
  }
```

This should give 'retryData' field missing

```
let runtimeObjectFormat = {
    data: 'someDifferentValue',
    errors: 'someDifferentValue',
    abort: 'someDifferentValue',
    retryData: 'someDifferentValue',
    extraField: 'someDifferentValue
  }
```

This should give 'extraField' field is unexpected

Can someone provide Javascript code for same?

Comment: Please share your attempts to solve the issue. By the way, would using TypeScript be an available option?

Comment: Use `hasOwnProperty`. Write a script that checks an object for each property e.g: `if (runtimeObjectFormat.hasOwnProperty('extraField')) {
   // do something
}`

Also to get all keys in object - you can loop them e.g: `for(var key in runtimeObjectFormat) {
    var value = runtimeObjectFormat[key];
}`

Comment: I use jsonschema for that : https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema you can validate type, minimum/maximum value or length, use regex patterns and so on, it generates error messages for you. It's a powerful tool

Comment: @Beni Sinca I dont know the exactName of extraField that would be present.
It can be anything ExtraField1 or ExtraField2 or anything random 'xyz'

Comment: You can extract all keys from your template object and from the object you want to test using `Object.keys()`, then you can find all missing attributes by filtering the template keys and returning the ones that are not in the test object  (`array.prototype.filter(key => !testObkectKeys.includes(key))`) and all extra keys by filtering all test object keys that are not included in the template (`array.prototype.filter(key => !templateKeys.includes(key))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrote a function for this use case

```
function checkObjectFormat(runtimeObj, expectedObj){
    let runtimeKeys = Object.keys(runtimeObj);
    let expKeys = Object.keys(expectedObj);

    let extraFields = runtimeKeys.filter(x => !expKeys.includes(x));
    let missingFields = expKeys.filter(x => !runtimeKeys.includes(x));

    return {
        extraFields,
        missingFields
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
checkObjectFormat(runtimeObjectFormat, expectedObjectFormat)
```

It will return a object that contains array of `extra` and `missing` fields

Output for a object with extra key:

```
{
    "extraFields": [
        "extraField"
    ],
    "missingFields": []
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not show any effort on the OP side; this "encourages" people to post questions that do not respect the community standards

Comment: @secan I will surely keep that in mind for future.